# How to match the type of an array in Scala?

Tags: scala

Given a function that receives a parameter `arr : Array[Any]`, how can I match the type of `Any` in a pattern? More, importantly, how can I match multiple cases at the same time?

Currently I have

```
def matchType (arr: Array[Any]) = {

    arr match {
        case a @ ( _: Array[Int] | _: Array[Long] | _: Array[Double] ) => arr.map(*...*);
        case b: Array[Byte] => print("byte")
        case _ => print("unknown")
    }        

}
```

which fails to compile with

```
cmd8.sc:4: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : Array[Int]
 required: Array[Any]
Note: Int <: Any, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
            case a @ ( _: Array[Int] | _: Array[Long] | _: Array[Double] ) => print("numerical");
                          ^
cmd8.sc:4: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : Array[Long]
 required: Array[Any]
Note: Long <: Any, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
            case a @ ( _: Array[Int] | _: Array[Long] | _: Array[Double] ) => print("numerical");
                                          ^
cmd8.sc:4: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : Array[Double]
 required: Array[Any]
Note: Double <: Any, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
            case a @ ( _: Array[Int] | _: Array[Long] | _: Array[Double] ) => print("numerical");
                                                           ^
cmd8.sc:5: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : Array[Byte]
 required: Array[Any]
Note: Byte <: Any, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
            case b: Array[Byte] => print("byte")
                    ^
Compilation Failed
```

Comment: Arrays are invariant in the type of elements. If you have an `Array[Any]`, then you have an `Array[Any]`, and that's it. It cannot possibly be an `Array[Int]` or `Array[Byte]` or anything else, unless you've wrongfully cast it into `Array[Any]`. Even the sizeof elements (64bit vs 32bit vs 8bit) is different. What is it that you are *actually* trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. I am trying to implement a function that could receive an `Array` of arbitrary type and perform a series of operations (such as `map()`) on certain types and perform different operations on other types. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You could take `Array[Any]` and then handle the various `case`s for different types *inside* of the `map`. But that's quite ugly. It would be much better if you explained how you lost the type of the array in the first place. And providing an [mcve] of how you would like to use your function would make your question much clearer.

Comment: That would make the correct argument type `Array[_]`, not `Array[Any]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot match the whole `Array` but you can match each element in turn:

```
def matchType (arr: Array[_]) =
  arr.foreach{
    case _: Double | _: Float => println("floating")
    case i: Int => println("int")
    case b: Byte => println("byte")
    case _ => println("other")
  }
```

Since `Array[Any]` could have a mixture of underlying types you can't convert to an `Array` of another type without checking each element in turn.

Comment: Nice. Thank you for clarifying. It has cleared up my confusion regarding the matchability of arrays. I will accept this answer as the closest possible to solution to my initial idea.